# subprocess.Popen error : Not iterable

Tags: python

i got a question that is driving me crazy, im starting to create some helpful scripts for my work.. scripting in python 2.7.. im following a book called "Python for Unix and Linux administrators.." well i know i should be programming in python 3 but for the moment Python 2.7 gives me solutions.. so im creating a script that use the subprocess module.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen


nmap = "nmap"
argumento_nmap = "-p"
port_nmap = "22"
port2_nmap = "2104"
open_port = "open"
closed_port = "closed"
ip_nmap = "192.168.170.52"

escaneo = subprocess.Popen([nmap,argumento_nmap,puerto_nmap,ip_nmap],         
stdout=PIPE)
print(escaneo.communicate()[0].split())
scan_result = escaneo
if port_nmap in scan_result:
    print " Puerto abierto"
```

in my mind ... the script should verificate if the the open_port ( 22 ) is open or closed.. but everytime i run the code i get next error :
    TypeError: argument of type 'Popen' is not iterable
.. searching on the web i found some functions like check_output() but they does not help me.. is there a way to check if that variable is into the scan_result list ?

sorry for my poor english and i hope you guyz got the problems..

Greets

Esteban

Comment: Why did you write `scan_result = escaneo`? `escaneo` isn't a scan result.

Comment: Because i tought i could convert the result in a string.. That is not relevant in the code..

Answer (score 1):

The specific error you are getting is because `x in y` expects y to be an iterator, that python will search within for x.   I think that you want to set `scan_result = escaneo.communicate()[0]`. That returns a string with stdout, so `if port_nmap in scan_result:` will work. However, it will return true if the string '22' appears anywhere in the string, so you might want to do a split as in your print statement.

Answer (score 0):

thx for answer to me @rcriii i could research more for the problem i had and found a solution.... `scan_result = escaneo.communicate[0]`  that code didnt work for me.. its gave me the next error : `TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` but your answer gave me force to research more.. so at 3.00 am i could get what i want..  here is the code

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT 
nmap = "nmap"
argumento_nmap = "-p"
port_nmap = "22"
port2_nmap = "2104"
open_port = "open"
closed_port = "closed"
ip_nmap = "localhost"
salida = "stdout.txt"
atributos_salida = "wb"
error = "stderr.txt"
atributos_error = "wb"
lista = Popen([nmap, argumento_nmap, port_nmap,ip_nmap], stdin=PIPE,          stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
resultado = lista.communicate()[0]
print resultado
```

thx mate! and if u have any suggestions please

greetz

Esteban

Comment: Hi Esteban, You have it. `listo.communicate` is a method, while `listo.communicate()` gives the return value of the function, which is a tuple with a `__getitem__` method. I've updated my answer above to correct the error.

Comment: thx mate for your help.. now i got some other doubts... should i open a new thread for this ? im new in stack overflow.. but the doubts are related to this code..

Comment: I'm not a SO expert, but if it is unrelated to this issue (even in the same code), I'd ask a different question. Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask?

Comment: thx you mate i read it and yes.. the problem i got ( that i found a solution ) was not a Popen error.. have a nice day